# dynamic variable array name in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

i am wondering about how to implement a dynamic increment variable,
this is my php

```
<?php 

$sections =5;

for($g=1; $g<=$sections; $g++){
$smarty->assign(array(
        'products-'.$g => $dbvariable,
        'add_display-'.$g => $othervar ));
}

$smarty->assign('number', $sections);
?>
```

this is my smarty template

```
{assign var=cnt value=1}
{while $cnt <= $number}
{foreach from=$products-`.$cnt` item=prod name=mysection}
<div class="section-{$cnt}">
// my output here
 <h3>{$products-`$cnt`.name}</h3>
  <img src="{$add_display-`$cnt`.src}">
</div>
{/foreach}
{assign var=cnt value=$cnt+1}
{/while}
```

can anyone guide me on how to implement the increment dynamic variable on smarty?

it seems like I'm lost here

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a reason for the approach you've started down, but this will be easier to read as an answer than a comment.

Rather than dynamic variable names, why not just use arrays? This should be equivalent to what you want, I think:

```
<?php 

$sections =5;

$products = array();
$add_display = array();
for($g=1; $g<=$sections; $g++){
    $products[$g] = $dbvariable;
    $add_display[$g] = $othervar;
}

$smarty->assign('products', $products);
$smarty->assign('add_display', $add_display);
$smarty->assign('number', $sections);
```

And then (this could probably be simplified further, but I've left it as similar to yours as possible so you can see what I've changed):

```
{assign var=cnt value=1}
{while $cnt <= $number}
    {foreach from=$products[$cnt] item=prod name=mysection}
    <div class="section-{$cnt}">
        // my output here
        <h3>{$prod.name}</h3>
        <img src="{$add_display[$cnt].src}">
    </div>
    {/foreach}
{assign var=cnt value=$cnt+1}
{/while}
```

Incidentally, that `<h3>` didn't look quite right, so I've guessed at what it should have been.

Comment: thank you so much, i have tried this method. but it didnt give me my desired results.
the $products is already an array. and putting the array on an array gives me the dizzy.. hehe 
you helped me a bit on it. i appreciate it

Comment: If a 2-dimensional array (a very common structure in PHP code, so will have plenty of examples to look at) confuses you, then dynamically named variables (which are very unusual, and not well-supported by most functions) will be worse, not better.

Comment: owh? really? ill take note that